# angularjs : trying to display a template when page submited

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I have a form when submitted will evoke  "ng-submit="submit()" function inside the WelcomeController.

here i make an ajax request and checks if there is a status is equal to success. the status may not be updated in the DB when the ajax call is done.So i have set a settimeout to call make the ajax request again and again every 6 seconds till we get a status as success. What i want is to during this checking time is to  load another template.

this is the code.

```
app.controller('WelcomeController', function($http,$scope,$location){
   $scope.email="abcd@test.com";


    $scope.submit = function(){
        //some way to set a new template
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'check',
            data: {email: $scope.email},
       }).success(function(data){
         if(data=="mailreceived"){
                //redirect to another page
               window.location.assign("./score");
         }else{
             //rcheck again if the status is set
             setTimeout( $scope.submit, 6000 );
              return false;
         }
       });  
     }
})
```

Comment: logic seems fuzzy.... why won't the first request return your success message? Seems like you want the re-submit in `error` callback. If user offline however the continuous loop it would go on indefinitely if used in `error` callback

Comment: i have changed that from success to mail received, Basically the app is trying to check if a mail is received with the posted email id. Sometimes the mail may get delayed. So instead of asking the user to re-post it we are doing it using settimeout and during that rechecking time i have to show another template.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem here? It doesn't redirect you?

Did you try using [AngularJS location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)

Comment: it is redirecting.....Basically the app is making an ajax request and trying to check if a mail is received with the posted email id. Sometimes the mail may get delayed. So instead of asking the user to re-post it we are doing it using settimeout and during that rechecking time i have to show another template..